# How to update UI on page load from rest service

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm stuck with a problem of getting the UI in angular2 to populate a drop-down list with data upon load.

I have a service, which connects to our internal SDK, in the sdk we have rest end-points that return observable, so in my code i make a call to that method on the sdk which returns an observable and subscribe to it to receive data, this is working, as i can see it in the network tab i get data back, however my UI does not get populated instead, oddly enugh, when i click the submit button the values appear or as an experiment, i added a url that with a hash value, when i click on it, that too seems to trigger the UI and the drop-down list receives the data, why is that and how do i get it to just populate without needs to submit anything?

```
export class RequestFormComponent implements OnInit{
  reqForm: FormGroup;
  resultDetails: any[] = [];

constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private requestDetails: DataServices) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.reqForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      acceptedTermsAndConditions: [false, Validators.pattern('true')],
      itemSelection: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });

    this.getSaleItems();
  }

 getSaleItems(): void {
    this.requestDetails.getForSaleItems()
    .subscribe( (data) => this.resultDetails.push( data[0].itemsLIst ));
  };
```

The form:

```
<form class="saleForm"
          novalidate
          (ngSubmit)="fullfillSale()"
          [formGroup]="saleForm">

<select class="lngField" id="itemSelection" formControlName="itemSelection"> <option disabled="disabled" value="">-- Please select an Item --</option> <option *ngFor="let details of resultDetails">Item: {{ details.description }}</option> </select> 

</form>
```

Comment: Can you post a code snippet to show how you are binding your items to the drop-down list?

Comment: I've update my post with some sample code

Comment: At first glance I thought you'd want to bind a value for each `option` .. e.g. `<option *ngFor="let details of resultDetails" [value]="details.someKey">Item: {{ details.description }}</option>`

When the data comes back, does this.resultDetails have what you expect? Is data[0].itemsLIst a typo?

Comment: Yes it returns the correct data, returns several objects so I have to further into it to get what i need.

Comment: @Beto, I realize this is probably due to posting the question, but as a comment, you are using two different formgroups `reqForm` and `saleForm` in your question...

Comment: Can't you assign `this.resultDetails` directly instead of pushing into it? I.e. `this.resultDetails.push = data[0].itemsLIst`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the final release or newer you can loose the `FormBuilder` and simply use [`FormGroup` & `FormControl`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html)

As for the code, I suspect your issue is here `this.resultDetails.push(data[0].itemsLIst)`.
Is `itemsLIst` an array? If so you should use `this.resultDetails.push(...data[0].itemsLIst);`

Here is a working plnkr using FormGroup: [Select Updated By Service](http://plnkr.co/edit/CUYkquejL7aKFjP6wdFT?p=preview)